# TensorFlow Transform Python using AWS S3 as data source

Tags: apache-beam-io, tensorflow-transform

I am trying to run TensorFlow Transform, using Python, Apache Flink as the Beam Runner. I noticed that Beam does not have AWS S3 as the io connector, and would like to know any work around for this.

Here is the [list](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/) of supported io connectors, but Python+S3 is not even in the roadmap.

I can think of two work around:

1. mount the S3 bucket as a local drive to a EC2 instance
2. Write my own Python S3 connector using [their guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/developing-io-python/).

I want to know if there are other creative (easy) way out.

Thanks!